# How to find Knowledge Article Type?

Tags: apex, knowledge

I am querying the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` table to list all articles in order to display a list of links to articles.

Because of some limitations I cannot use the `<knowledge:articleList>` tag.

I have these article types: `Documentation__kav`, `FAQ__kav`, `Private_Article__kav`.

Other article types will be added later.

How do I find out the article type from the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` table?

Maybe there are other tables I can query to find this out?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the ERD diagram in the [Articles](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_knowledge.htm) online documentation should help.

Comment: It should, but it doesn't :)

Answer (score 4):

I found how to do it.

As @scyforce said I need to use the key prefix.

[Link on Salesforce Community](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/finding-out-articletype-from-knowledgeArticleVersion/td-p/334173)

Code from that page:

```
    // Create DescribeMap
    private void createDescribeMap() {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Set<String> keySet = gd.keySet();
        for (String key : keySet) {
            Schema.SObjectType objectType = gd.get(key);
            if (key.endsWith('ka') || key.endsWith('kb')) {
                this.describeMap.put(objectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(), objectType.getDescribe().getLabel());
            }
        }
    }

    //Util method to get Article Type from article Id.
    public String getArticleType(String articleId) {
        String articlePrefix = articleId.substring(0,3);
        Set<String> keySet = describeMap.keySet();
        String articleType = null;
        for(String key: keySet) {
            if(articlePrefix.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                articleType = describeMap.get(key);
                return articleType;
            }
        }
        return articleType;
    }
```

Comment: One suggestion, when putting the values in the describeMap, convert the keyPrefix to lower case. Then you don't need the for loop and equalsIgnoreCase in getArticleType.

Comment: Also, is there something special about key prefixes that end in 'ka' or 'kb'? I'm not sure that it is correct. E.g. the key prefix from 'ka4S0000000CaTSIA0' wouldn't match. I suspect it should be checking that the objecttype ends with '__kav'.

Answer (score 3):

5 years later and this data is now exposed on the KnowledgeArticleVersion table itself.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm

```
ArticleType
Type: string
Properties: Defaulted on create,Filter
Description: Indicates the API Name of the article type.  
    The ArticleType is assigned to the article when it's created. 
    You can't change the value of this field.  
    This field is available in API version 26.0 and later.
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to have a key prefix mapping table in order to find the article type. Thanks.

Comment: So does the key prefix on the KnowledgeArticleVersion.Id change based on the article type? Or is it another field?

Comment: @scyforce:  I'm not sure what this means.  Could you flesh out this answer a bit more or give an example of how you'd use a "key prefix mapping table"?